# opentable embedded postgresql not working

Tags: java, postgresql, in-memory-database

I am using [otj-pg-embedded](https://github.com/opentable/otj-pg-embedded) for the first time and would like to incorporate it into our test framework. Details are as follows

Following is the maven dependency :

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opentable.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>otj-pg-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

And the code is :

```
EmbeddedPostgres pg = EmbeddedPostgres.start();
 Connection connection = pg.getPostgresDatabase().getConnection();
 Statement s = connection.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT 1");
 assertEquals(1, rs.getInt(1));
```

But it fails with java.lang.IllegalStateException on line 1 of the code.

Stack trace is :

```
initdb: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process [/var/folders/rj/3jd5_2n16g37lv1v550g9cqw0000gp/T/embedded-pg/PG-b210101549c90a94dbbada389b65c5d2/bin/initdb, -A, trust, -U, postgres, -D, /var/folders/rj/3jd5_2n16g37lv1v550g9cqw0000gp/T/epg2729813194709143982, -E, UTF-8] failed


        at com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres.system(EmbeddedPostgres.java:593)
        at com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres.initdb(EmbeddedPostgres.java:230)
        at com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres.<init>(EmbeddedPostgres.java:148)
        at com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres$Builder.start(EmbeddedPostgres.java:580)
        at com.opentable.db.postgres.embedded.EmbeddedPostgres.start(EmbeddedPostgres.java:480)
```

Is there anything that I am missing to configure here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace ?

Comment: Updated question with stack trace.

Comment: Updated stack trace again.

Comment: @VikasGite did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at this line in the stack trace
`initdb: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables`,

It seems you need to set env variables for locale as described here: https://github.com/zonkyio/embedded-postgres/issues/11.

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
EmbeddedPostgres pg = EmbeddedPostgres.builder().start();

//Get the connection to postgres db
Statement dbSetup = pg.getDatabase("postgres", "postgres").getConnection().createStatement();

//Then create a db as per your requirement with appropriate user and password if required.
dbSetup.execute("create database testdatabase;");
dbSetup.execute("CREATE USER testadmin WITH PASSWORD 'testadmin' CREATEDB;");
dbSetup.execute("ALTER USER testadmin WITH SUPERUSER;"); 
dbSetup.execute("ALTER ROLE testadmin SUPERUSER;");

// Connect to the created database and work
pg.getDatabase("testadmin", "testdatabase").getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("select 1;");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it upgrading to the latest version of `otj-pg-embedded`.

for instance on gradle set:

```
testImplementation "com.opentable.components:otj-pg-embedded:1.0.0"
```

The initialization of the db faced a lot of problems with binaries, and finally at the end of this long commented ticket, [Fail on OSX suddenly. · Issue #136 · opentable/otj-pg-embedded](https://github.com/opentable/otj-pg-embedded/issues/136), I found the real solution.

On Jan 2022 the library switched to version 1, which conveniently uses [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/). This finally solved my problems, and I didn't look at it any deeper. My understanding is that much of the compatibility problems between the library itself, Postgres, and the OS should have gone thanks to using isolated containers.